# converting a function into jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got two functions, one to parse an html string to get its headers into an array

```js
const str = "<h1>test-1<h1><h2>test1-1<h2><h3>test1-1-1</h3><h1>test1-2<h1><h2>test1-2-1</h2><h3>test1-2-2</h3><h1>test-2</h1><h1>test-3</h1><h1>test-4</h1>
"
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = str.trim();

let tree = [];
let leaf = null;

for (const node of wrapper.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"))
{
    const nodeLevel = parseInt(node.tagName[1]);
    const newLeaf = { level: nodeLevel, text: node.textContent, children: [], parent: leaf };

    while (leaf && newLeaf.level <= leaf.level)
        leaf = leaf.parent;

    if (!leaf)
        tree.push(newLeaf);
    else
        leaf.children.push(newLeaf);

    leaf = newLeaf;
}
```

and another to parse those headers into a list for a table of contents feature

```js
const ol = document.createElement("ol");

(function makeOl(ol, leaves)
{
    for (const leaf of leaves)
    {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(new Text(leaf.text));

        if (leaf.children.length > 0)
        {
            const subOl = document.createElement("ol");
            makeOl(subOl, leaf.children);
            li.appendChild(subOl);
        }

        ol.appendChild(li);
    }
})(ol, tree);
```

it outputs a string like this

```
"<ol><li>test-1<ol><li>test1-1<ol><li>test1-1-1</li></ol></li><li>test1-2<ol><li>test1-2-1</li><li>test1-2-2</li></ol></li></ol></li><li>test-2</li><li>test-3</li><li>test-4</li></ol>"
```

which renders to something like

1. test-1

   1. test1-1

      1. test1-1-1
   2. test1-2

      1. test1-2-1
      2. test1-2-2
2. test-2
3. test-3
4. test-4

I'm still getting used to the jsx part of React and I'm wondering how to convert that function so that the ol's and li's are React/jsx elements rather than a string of raw html as that'd require another step to render eg.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: olString}} />
```

the way I'm using to using jsx with arrays is something like this

```
const list = tree.map((headers) => <li>{headers.value}</li>)
<div><ul>{list}</ul></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. JSX is just a syntax specification. Are you just trying to rebuild your parsed HTML tree as a tree of React element nodes?

Comment: @LINKIWI, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

e.g.

```
React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
```

But, best practice might be something like this.

```js
// reusable Tree component
export default class Tree extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  }

  render() {

    const { children } = this.props

    return (
      <ol>
        {children.map(leaf =>
          <li key={leaf.id}>
            <span>{leaf.text}</span>
            {leaf.children && <Tree children={leaf.children}/>}
          </li>
        )}
      </ol>
    )
  }
}

// (re)use it 
function render() {
  return (
    <Tree children={ tree } />
  );
}
```

You could even make the HTML Elements variable.

```
<Tree children={ tree } listNode="ul" listElementNode="li" />
```

then in the Tree component

```
function render() {
    const {listNode: UL, listElementNode: LI} = this.props;
    return (<UL></UL>);
}
```

Comment: While I'm pretty sure this is what OP is trying to accomplish, to answer the question directly of how to convert into JSX *syntax*, you could do `const Elem = 'li'; return <Elem>...</Elem>`

Comment: I´m writing this at the moment. :)

Comment: do you have a unqiue ´id´ in every of your list elements?

Comment: seems to create empty ol tags after each h3

Comment: well, that is then some implementation issue. I can quite confidently assure you, that my answer is working in general. I would suggest, you update your code/question with what you got. alternatively, create a new question with the code you have and the problem/errors you get.

Comment: your answer does work and it works great, it's just creating an additional empty ol tag after each h. you can see it after test-1 and test1-1-1, at https://codesandbox.io/s/qkw75klqmj

Comment: but that seems to be because of your parsing. I console.log out the tree before running react and there are already empty nodes there.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have a recursive function (`makeOl`), which i replaced with a `renderLeaf` function:

a way to render this would be:

```
class Tree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let leafs = this.props.children
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {leafs.map(this.renderLeaf)}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
  renderLeaf(leaf) {
    return (
      <ol>
        <li>
          {leaf.text}
          {leaf.children && leaf.children.map(this.renderLeaf)}
        </li>
      </ol>
    )
  }
}
```

you can then use this as: `<Tree children={tree} />`